# What does 'Icier' mean? Question about a review of Elementary in the Washington Post

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the following article: [CBS’s ‘Elementary’: Sherlock, rehabbed](https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/tv/elementary-sherlock-rehabbed/2012/09/13/2ea9841e-fdd1-11e1-a31e-804fccb658f9_story.html?utm_term=.6b8df47f2d44) in the Washington Post from September 13, 2012 and in particular this part.

"...
“Elementary” exhibits enough stylish wit in its mood and look to quickly distinguish itself from the latest British “Sherlock” series (seen on PBS), in which Benedict Cumberbatch (or Bandersnatch Cummerbund, as my colleague Lisa de Moraes likes to call him) plays a far **icier** version of the character. 
..."

Considering that I recently Tweeted:
"... #JohnnyLeeMiller is a worthy successor of #JeremyBrett (pic) as #Holmes, while #Sherlock / #BenedictCumberbatch is a disgrace to the #legacy ..." I don't understand the term 'icier' at all.

I meant that in Elementary Holmes is a 201x version of the original Holmes where the Holmes in Sherlock acts more as a clown, a person in need of psychiatric help.

What do you think the Washington Post meant with 'icier'?

Answer (score 5):

Describing a person as "icy" states that they are unfriendly, cold, emotionless:

> a. Unfriendly or hostile: an icy stare.
>   b. Showing no emotion: icy detachment.

From [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/icier)

Thus, describing someone as playing a far icier version of the character implies that the portrayal is colder, unfriendlier or less emotional than any other portrayal the reviewer is familiar with.

Comment: Yes, I looked up 'icier' of course. I imagined there was another meaning of the word because Sherlock is not more icy than his New York City counterpart.